# Netlink broadcast b/w 2 kernel module and 1 userspace process.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, netlink

Is it possible for user space to broadcast or multicast to more then one (2) kernel modules via NETLINK socket?